# Zerobrane intepreter path on linux (corona & wine)

Tags: linux, coronasdk, wine, zerobrane

i've made corona sdk works on linux with wine, all is fine except zerobrane interpreter path. i got that => 
run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for /home/zed/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Corona Labs/Corona/Corona Simulator.exe

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the correct location of the Corona Simulator executable is in your case, but you can always set it manually using `path.corona` setting, as described in the [documentation](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-general-preferences#interpreter-path).